# Rewriting an equation to include a condition

Tags: soft-question

I have a simple equation: a = b(c/d)

but it has a condition: if b > 1, then b = 1

How do I write this condition into the equation?

Answer (score 1):

$$a=\min(b,1)\cdot(c/d){}{}{}$$

Answer (score -1):

Your question is really not a physics question, but a mathematical one. However, the way to add in the condition is the following:

$$
a = \begin{cases}\left(\frac{c}{d}\right) & {\rm if}\,b>1 \\ b\left(\frac{c}{d}\right) & {\rm otherwise}\end{cases}
$$

The long brace is the `cases` environment in [latex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX): `$\begin{cases} ...stuff...\end{cases}$`

Comment: Thank you for answer, however I was hoping for an equation that includes a portion which subtracts (or divides) back out the amount that b is greater than 1.  I know I have seen this technique used in other equations, but I can't remember how it is done.

Comment: So you're looking for something involving the [Heaviside step function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function)??